# Drawing a Moving Grid on Android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, grid

Is it possible to create and draw a Moving Grid on a canvas that recycles its points? I want to create a Grid on an android canvas that moves downwards and recycles its points when a point reaches the bottom of the screen.

The First part of the question is: How do I draw a grid with lines on an Android Canvas?
The Second part: How do I make it scroll and repeat?
The grid should look something like this:

[image]

I have tried doing this with a Bitmap , but I am not sure if that is as efficient as doing it By using the Draw Line feature. Plus, I cannot access the girds points when using a bitmap, so it is not very useful when trying to draw a graph for example.

Comment: Gotta love people that downvote a question and don't even tell me why.

Comment: I don't presume to know why people vote, but you seem to have answered your first question, and you've shown no attempt at addressing the second. So your post could seem like a request for someone to write code for you.

Comment: Oh. I wasnt asking for code. I was merely looking for some suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: I would draw the grid manually. It's gotta be better, performance-wise, than redrawing a complete Bitmap every frame. It'll a little more complicated coding, but if you need the grid coordinates anyway, it's then pretty much just a couple loops with `drawLine()` calls more.

Comment: Ok thanks, just wasnt sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a drawing app, and I encountered the same problem. I searched everywhere, but I could not found a direct solution. That is why I developed a library that do exactly that. It creates a infinite grid that can be transformed, include transformations are: **Translate**, **Rotate** and **Scale**. The library generates only the visible lines, that are shown on the View and are generated in real time using simple math. Here is a direct link to the [library](https://github.com/slaviboy/InfiniteGridView)

[image]

The explanation is pretty simple, if you want to learn more about how it works your can check the [Wiki](https://github.com/slaviboy/InfiniteGridView/wiki) page.

Here is a link to the library [source code](https://github.com/slaviboy/InfiniteGridView/tree/master/infinitegridview/src/main/java/com/slaviboy/infinitegridview), if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

To tag onto Balha's answer:

the android/java equivalent looks something like this:

```
int canvasWidth = 0;
int canvasHeight = 0;
float gridSize = 20f;
float ecart = Math.max(mCanvasHeight, mCanvasWidth) / gridSize;
//last j index value
int lj= 0;
//last i index value
int li = 0;
canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
for (int j = 0; j <= Math.min(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); j += (int)ecart)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Math.max(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); i += (int)ecart)
    {
        li = i;
    }
    lj = j;
 }

 canvas.clipRect(0, 0, lj, canvas.getHeight());

 for (int j = 0; j <= Math.min(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); j += (int)ecart)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i <= Math.max(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); i += (int)ecart)
     {
        //horizontal lines
        canvas.drawLine(j, i, i, i, paint);

         //vertical lines
         canvas.drawLine(j, i, j, j, paint);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but It can help someone else; 
This Draws a perfect grid mesh
Note: This is a c# code

```
        float gridSize = 20f;
   var ecart = Math.Max(MaxHeight, MaxWidth) / gridSize;

    //last j index value
    int lj= 0;
    //last i index value
    int li = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= Math.Min(canvas.Width, canvas.Height); j += (int)ecart)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(canvas.Width, canvas.Height); i += (int)ecart)
        {
            li = i;
        }
        lj = j;
    }
    canvas.ClipRect(0, 0, lj, canvas.Height);

    for (int j = 0; j <= Math.Min(canvas.Width, canvas.Height); j += (int)ecart)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(canvas.Width, canvas.Height); i += (int)ecart)
        {
            //horizontal lines
            canvas.DrawLine(j, i, i, i, paint);

            //vertical lines
            canvas.DrawLine(j, i, j, j, paint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: android apps can be written in many languages nowadays, including c#